# Remove element from collection during iteration with forEach

Tags: swift

Recently, I wrote this code without thinking about it very much:

```
myObject.myCollection.forEach { myObject.removeItem($0) }
```

where `myObject.removeItem(_)` removes an item from `myObject.myCollection`.

Looking at the code now, I am puzzled as to why this even works - shouldn't I get an exception along the lines of `Collection was mutated while being enumerated`?
The same code even works when using a regular for-in loop!

Is this expected behaviour or am I 'lucky' that it isn't crashing?

Comment: Word of warning: `removeItem(_:)` is `O(n)`, as is `forEach(_:)`. This line is `O(n^2)` in total. Might be worth using set arithmetic.

Comment: It's not necessarily `O(n)` - sets are `O(1)`. I supply the `removeItem(_:)` method myself (there is no such method on a swift collection), and do some other teardown-stuff in there.

Comment: Also, this collection typically contains 2-4 items, so I took the potential runtime hit knowingly ;)

Comment: Okay good. It was worth mentioning to be sure

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is indeed expected behaviour – and is due to the fact that an `Array` in Swift (as well as many other collections in the standard library) is a value type with copy-on-write semantics. This means that its underlying buffer (which is stored indirectly) will be *copied* upon being mutated (and, as an optimisation, only when it's not uniquely referenced).

When you come to iterate over a `Sequence` (such as an array), be it with `forEach(_:)` or a standard `for in` loop, an iterator is created from the sequence's [`makeIterator()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641667-makeiterator) method, and its [`next()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/iteratorprotocol/1641682-next) method is repeatedly applied in order to sequentially generate elements.

You can think of iterating over a sequence as looking like this:

```
let sequence = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var iterator = sequence.makeIterator()

// `next()` will return the next element, or `nil` if
//  it has reached the end sequence.
while let element = iterator.next() { 
    // do something with the element
}
```

In the case of `Array`, an [`IndexingIterator`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/indexingiterator) is used as its iterator – which will iterate through the elements of a given collection by simply *storing that collection* along with the current index of the iteration. Each time `next()` is called, the base collection is subscripted with the index, which is then incremented, until it reaches `endIndex` (you can see its [exact implementation here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/bd1ce98e4b757cd97eb74cec70e067796876c898/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L69)).

Therefore, when you come to mutate your array in the loop, its underlying buffer is *not* uniquely referenced, as the iterator also has a view onto it. This forces a copy of the buffer – which `myCollection` then uses.

So, there are now two arrays – the one which is being iterated over, and the one you're mutating. Any further mutations in the loop won't trigger another copy, as long as `myCollection`'s buffer remains uniquely referenced.

This therefore means that it's perfectly safe to mutate a collection with value semantics while enumerating over it. The enumeration will iterate over the full length of the collection – completely independant of any mutations you do, as they will be done on a copy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I supply the `removeItem(_:)` method myself (there is no such method for a swift collection, and the name is only a placeholder to make my point clear), and do some other teardown-stuff for the removed object in there, so I cannot simply call `removeAll()` on the collection.

Comment: @David Ah okay, makes sense now. Happy to help :)

Comment: Hi @DavidGanster, sorry to bother you such a long time after you posted the question. Just to let you know that I did quite a hefty edit to this answer today, as I wasn't too happy with the original version. If you have time, feel free to take a glance over it and check that you're still happy with it – I'm happy to answer any questions :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I think it improves the quality of the answer quite a bit :)

Comment: Great! But why didn't Apple introduce this in programing guide?

Answer (score 16):

I asked a [similar question](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8551) in the Apple Developer
Forum and the answer is "yes, because of the value semantics of Array".

@originaluser2 said that already, but I would argue slightly different:
When `myObject.removeItem($0)` is called, a *new array* is created and
stored under the name `myObject`, but the array that `forEach()` was called upon is not modified.

Here is a simpler example demonstrating the effect:

```
extension Array {
    func printMe() {
        print(self)
    }
}

var a = [1, 2, 3]
let pm = a.printMe // The instance method as a closure.
a.removeAll() // Modify the variable `a`.
pm() // Calls the method on the value that it was created with.
// Output: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Indeed, that's a much clearer example than mine :) The principle is the same though – `a.removeAll()` will make a copy of `a`, remove all the elements, then assign that back to `a`. The original value of `a` is unaffected, and you can keep it retained via keeping a reference to one of its instance methods, and call it later to demonstrate this.

Comment: @originaluser2: Yes, the difference in the argumentation is marginal. You said (if I interpret it correctly) that the iterator gets a copy of the array. I say that the iterator operators on the original array, and mutating that makes a copy. But as you can see from my question in the forum, it took me quite a while to get it.

Comment: Surely both make a (theoretical) copy? The iterator has to make a copy as it's initialised with the original array, which is then assigned to an internal property (value types dicate that that should make a copy) – and then mutating will always make a copy, do the mutation and then re-assign.

Comment: @originaluser2: Yes, the Iterator is created with a copy (`return IndexingIterator(_elements: self)` in https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift). My argumentation is that the observed behaviour  does not depend on making a copy, as my example (hopefully!) demonstrates. But I may be wrong of course!

Comment: Ah okay, I'm with you now – and you're indeed correct. The observed behaviour doesn't depend on making copy, therefore allowing the compiler will most probably optimise it away – so the actual copy will indeed be done when you come to mutate.

Answer (score 0):

The Collection was copied before starting the iteration , and the code inside Foreach is applied on the real collection but the iteration is happening on the copied Collection which will be deleted after the last iteration .