# Removing from set during enumeration in Swift?

Tags: swift, set, enumeration

Is it safe to delete an element from a set during enumeration?

```
for item in mySet {
    ...
    if needToRemove {
        mySet.remove(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use filter

Comment: e.g. `set.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }`

Comment: Yes, yes it is safe. `Set`, like many other collections in the standard library, is a value type – thus the set you're mutating and the set you're iterating over are independant from one another (see [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37997465/2976878)).

Comment: @RichTolley it would return an array. He would need to create a set from it `mySet = Set(mySet.filter { condition } )`

Comment: oops, so it would

Comment: @MartinR Yup, agreed. I was just sidetracked by the fact that I no longer really like my answer there, which I'm currently editing :P