# Is it safe to iterate an array while modifying it?

Tags: arrays, swift, iteration

I know you shouldn't, I kind of know why. But I mean I don't understand my own code once I am trying really to think what's going on.

So I have an array with bunch of objects. I am iterating over it and once I find an object with specific type, I remove it from the array, and add another object into the array. So something like this:

```
var arr = parent.allchildren() //getting all the children in array
for ele in arr{
   if(ele==somethingHere){
      parent.remove(ele)
      parent.add(new ele) //add new child into child array
   }
}
```

If I have an array of 1,2,3,4,5, and I remove 3 and add a 6 while iterating, the actual array would be 1,2,4,5,6 but the array I am iterating would still be 1,2,3,4,5.

Which I think it would be fine, because at the end I still get what I want, which removed the element and added the element I need. However modifying the list while iterating it is bad and you shouldn't do that, but for my case I think it does what I need. What could be the potential issue in my case that I can't see?

Comment: Related (if not duplicate): [Remove element from collection during iteration with forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37997465/1187415).

Comment: Is this even valid swift code? Did you mean to use `remove(at:)` and `append()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove element from collection during iteration with forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997465/remove-element-from-collection-during-iteration-with-foreach)

Comment: I just faced this issue of traversing an `unordered_set`, while simultaneously modifying it in CPP. I solved it by, starting with a random item, and then do the required changes, at the end of the iteration, delete the current item and select another random item. Continue till size > 0. But this will only work if the order of traversal is unimportant. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you may want to think about doing is making all of the changes at the end of the iteration. Instead of making the changes one by one, record the changes you want to make while iterating, and then actually make those changes once your loop is finished.

For example, you could make an array of elements to remove, and an array of elements to add.

```
//Our array where we record what we want to add
var elementsToAdd = [Any]()

//Our array of what elements we want to remove. We record the index at 
//which we want to remove the element from the array
var indexesToRemoveAt = [Int]()

//Getting all the children in array
var arr = parent.allchildren()

//Enumerating an array allows us to access the index at which that 
//element occurs. For example, the first element's index would be 0, 
//the second element's index would be 1, the third would be 2, and so 
//on
for (index,ele) in arr.enumerated() {
  if(ele == somethingHere) {
    indexesToRemoveAt.append(index)
    elementsToAdd.append(newEle)
   }
 }

 //Now that we have recorded the changes we want to make, we could make 
 //all of the changes at once
 arr.remove(at: indexesToRemoveAt)
 arr.append(contentsOf: elementsToAdd)
```

Note that removing array elements at multiple indexes would require the following extension to Array. If you wanted to avoid creating this extension, you could always just loop through the array of indexes and tell the array to remove at each individual index. All this extension function is really doing is looping through the indexes, and removing the array element at said index.

Array extension to remove elements at multiple indexes:

```
extension Array {
  //Allows us to remove at multiple indexes instead of just one
  mutating func remove(at indexes: [Int]) {
    for index in indexes.sorted(by: >) {
      if index <= count-1 {
        remove(at: index)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested in a playground with the following code:

```swift
var arr = ["hi", "bye", "guy", "fry", "sky"]

for a in arr {
    if arr.count >= 3 {
        arr.remove(at: 2)
    }
    print(a)
}

print(arr)
```

This prints:

```
hi
bye
guy
fry
sky
["hi", "bye"]
```

So it looks like when you use a `for-in` loop in Swift, the array is copied and changes you make to it will not affect the array you are iterating over. To answer your question, as long as you understand that this is the behavior, there's nothing wrong with doing this.

Comment: This is exactly what it already says at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37998032/341994 So the question is a duplicate and this answer is a duplicate of its answer. :(

Comment: Ok, let's flag this question as a duplicate then.