# Iterating with for .. in on a changing collection

Tags: swift, collections, iteration, language-lawyer, for-in-loop

I'm experimenting with iteration on an array using a `for .. in ..` loop.  My question is related to the case where the collection is changed within the loop body.

It seems that the iteration is safe, even if the list shrinks in the meantime.  The `for` iteration variables successively take the values of the (indexes and) elements that were in the array at the start of the loop, despite the changes made on the flow.  Example:

```
var slist = [ "AA", "BC", "DE", "FG" ]

for (i, st) in slist.enumerated() {   // for st in slist gives a similar result
    print ("Index \(i): \(st)")
    if st == "AA" {    // at one iteration change completely the list
        print (" --> check 0: \(slist[0]), and 2: \(slist[2])")
        slist.append ("KLM") 
        slist.insert(st+"XX", at:0)   // shift the elements in the array
        slist[2]="bc"                 // replace some elements to come
        print (" --> check again 0: \(slist[0]), and 2: \(slist[2])")
        slist.remove(at:3)
        slist.remove(at:3)
        slist.remove(at:1)            // makes list shorter
    }
}
print (slist)
```

This works very well, the iteration being made on the values `[ "AA", "BC", "DE", "FG" ]` even if after the first iteration the array is completely changed to `["AAXX", "bc", "KLM"]`

I wanted to know if I can safely rely on this behavior. Unfortunately,  the language guide does not tell anything about [iterating on a collection](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID111) when the collection is modified. And the [`for .. in` section](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID121) doesn't address this question either. So:

1. Can I safely rely on a guarantee about this iteration behavior provided in the language specifications ?
2. Or am I simply lucky with the current version of Swift 5.4? In this case, is there any clue in the language specification that one cannot take it for granted? And is there a performance overhead for this iteration behavior  (e.g. some copy) compared to indexed iteration?

Comment: `enumerated` returns a sequence so this is what you are iterating over and not the array you are changing within the loop. So it is two different objects. If you on the other hand use the index `i` to access the original array you can make it crash like `for (i, st) in slist.enumerated() { slist.remove(at: i) }`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson this is a very good remark.  However, I started this experiment without `enumerated()` and the result is the same (except that I don't have an index to display).  So there must be more. It's like a copy of the array would be performed for the iteration.

Comment: @Christophe this is copy on write, you are iterating over original array, and modifying new copies. It is important concept in Swift, but I don't know its official status in language reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? – [Remove element from collection during iteration with forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37997465/1187415)

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for this hint. I looked at the answers which are relevant (I upvoted Harmish’s and yours): The value semantic of the array are an interesting explanation that is experimentally confirmed. It’s also interesting to see that there are two cases: the array and the sequence via iterator. However I still miss the authoritative reference that would link the for…in to the value semantic (in case of an array). And for the iterator case, it is not clear to me if there is such a copy of the iterator on the underlying sequence, or if there is a read copy of the sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for [IteratorProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/iteratorprotocol) says "whenever you use a for-in loop with an array, set, or any other collection or sequence, you’re using that type’s iterator." So, we are guaranteed that a `for in` loop is going to be using `.makeIterator()` and `.next()` which is defined most generally on `Sequence` and `IteratorProtocol` respectively.

The documentation for [Sequence](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence) says that "the `Sequence` protocol makes no requirement on conforming types regarding whether they will be destructively consumed by iteration." As a consequence, this means that an iterator for a `Sequence` is not required to make a copy, and so I do not think that modifying a sequence while iterating over it is, in general, safe.

This same caveat does not occur in the documentation for [Collection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection), but I also don't think there is any guarantee that the iterator makes a copy, and so I do not think that modifying a collection while iterating over it is, in general, safe.

But, most collection types in Swift are `struct`s with value semantics or copy-on-write semantics. I'm not really sure where the documentation for this is, but [this link](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10) does say that "in Swift, `Array`, `String`, and `Dictionary` are all value types... You don’t need to do anything special — such as making an explicit copy — to prevent other code from modifying that data behind your back." In particular, this means that for `Array`, `.makeIterator()` *cannot* hold a reference to your array because the iterator for `Array` does not have to "do anything special" to prevent other code (i.e. your code) from modifying the data it holds.

We can explore this in more detail. The `Iterator` type of `Array` is [defined as](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688032-makeiterator) type `IndexingIterator<Array<Element>>`. The documentation [IndexingIterator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/indexingiterator) says that it is the default implementation of the iterator for collections, so we can assume that most collections will use this. We can see in [the source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/7123d2614b5f222d03b3762cb110d27a9dd98e24/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift) for `IndexingIterator` that it holds a *copy* of its collection

```swift
@frozen
public struct IndexingIterator<Elements: Collection> {
  @usableFromInline
  internal let _elements: Elements
  @usableFromInline
  internal var _position: Elements.Index

  @inlinable
  @inline(__always)
  /// Creates an iterator over the given collection.
  public /// @testable
  init(_elements: Elements) {
    self._elements = _elements
    self._position = _elements.startIndex
  }
  ...
}
```

and that the default `.makeIterator()` simply creates this copy.

```swift
extension Collection where Iterator == IndexingIterator<Self> {
  /// Returns an iterator over the elements of the collection.
  @inlinable // trivial-implementation
  @inline(__always)
  public __consuming func makeIterator() -> IndexingIterator<Self> {
    return IndexingIterator(_elements: self)
  }
}
```

Although you might not want to trust this source code, the documentation for [library evolution](https://swift.org/blog/library-evolution/) claims that "the `@inlinable` attribute is a promise from the library developer that the current definition of a function will remain correct when used with future versions of the library" and the `@frozen` also means that the members of `IndexingIterator` cannot change.

Altogether, this means that any collection type with value semantics and an `IndexingIterator` as its `Iterator` *must* make a copy when using using `for in` loops (at least until the next ABI break, which should be a long-way off). Even then, I don't think Apple is likely to change this behavior.

**In Conclusion**

I don't know of any place that it is explicitly spelled out in the docs "you can modify an array while you iterate over it, and the iteration will proceed as if you made a copy" but that's also the kind of language that probably shouldn't be written down as such code could definitely confuse a beginner.

However, there is enough documentation lying around which says that a `for in` loop just calls `.makeIterator()` and that for any collection with value semantics and the default iterator type (for example, `Array`), `.makeIterator()` makes a copy and so cannot be influenced by code inside the loop. Further, because `Array` and some other types like `Set` and `Dictionary` are copy-on-write, modifying these collections inside a loop will have a one-time copy penalty as the body of the loop will not have a unique reference to its storage (because the iterator will have a reference too). This is the exact same penalty that modifying the collection outside the loop will have if you don’t have a unique reference to the storage.

Without these assumptions, you aren't guaranteed safety, but you might have it anyway in some circumstances.

**Edit:**

I just realized we can create some cases where this is unsafe for sequences.

```swift
import Foundation

/// This is clearly fine and works as expected.
print("Test normal")
for _ in 0...10 {
    let x: NSMutableArray = [0,1,2,3]
    for i in x {
        print(i)
    }
}

/// This is also okay. Reassigning `x` does not mutate the reference that the iterator holds.
print("Test reassignment")
for _ in 0...10 {
    var x: NSMutableArray = [0,1,2,3]
    for i in x {
        x = []
        print(i)
    }
}

/// This crashes. The iterator assumes that the last index it used is still valid, but after removing the objects, there are no valid indices.
print("Test removal")
for _ in 0...10 {
    let x: NSMutableArray = [0,1,2,3]
    for i in x {
        x.removeAllObjects()
        print(i)
    }
}

/// This also crashes. `.enumerated()` gets a reference to `x` which it expects will not be modified behind its back.
print("Test removal enumerated")
for _ in 0...10 {
    let x: NSMutableArray = [0,1,2,3]
    for i in x.enumerated() {
        x.removeAllObjects()
        print(i)
    }
}
```

The fact that this is an `NSMutableArray` is important because this type has reference semantics. Since `NSMutableArray` conforms to `Sequence`, we know that mutating a sequence while iterating over it is not safe, even when using `.enumerated()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this well documented, logically structured and comprehensive answer. The references you have provided are exactly those that I was looking for. Could I summarize it as follows: it works well with standard collections, but this is far from guaranteed for a more general sequence; the iterator is the key to this behavior?

Comment: I'd say this is correct, the iterator is key. If the iterator does not make a copy, you cannot safely mutate inside an iteration, but if the iterator makes a copy (which is easy for types with value semantics, but could still work for reference semantics I suppose), mutating inside an iteration is safe.

Answer (score 1):

The `slist.enumerate()` create a new instance of   `EnumeratedSequence<[String]>`

> To create an instance of EnumeratedSequence, call enumerated() on a sequence or collection. The following example enumerates the elements of an array. [reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/enumeratedsequence)

If you remove the `.enumerate()` produce the same result, any `st` has the old value. This occurs because the `for-in loop` generates a new instance of `IndexingIterator<[String]>`.

> Whenever you use a for-in loop with an array, set, or any other collection or sequence, you’re using that type’s iterator. Swift uses a sequence’s or collection’s iterator internally to enable the for-in loop language construct. [reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/iteratorprotocol)

About the questions:

- You would be able to remove all the elements and still perform the loop safe because a new instance is generated to perform the interactions.
- Swift uses the iterator internally to enable for-in then there's no overhead to compare. Logically that the larger the array the performance will be affected.

Comment: Thank you for this well documented answer. The reference you have provided are indeed very helpful.