# What did Swift do to avoid that Collection was mutated while being enumerated?

Tags: swift, objective-c, collections, iteration, for-in-loop

In Swift , the following code works well

```
        var arr = [1, 2,3 ,4, 5, 6]
        for num in arr{
            arr.removeAll { val in
                return val == num
            }
        }
        print(arr)
```

the following Swift variation code works well too

```
        var arr = [1, 2,3 ,4, 5, 6]
        for num in arr.reversed(){
            arr.removeAll { val in
                return val == num
            }
        }
        print(arr)
```

while the following Objective - C code , crashed

```
    NSMutableArray * arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @11, @22, @33, @44, @55, @66, nil];
    for (NSObject * obj in arr) {
        [arr removeObject: obj];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", arr);
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x> was mutated while being enumerated.'

And the following Objective - C variation code, works well

```
    NSMutableArray * arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @11, @22, @33, @44, @55, @66, nil];
    for (NSObject * obj in arr.reverseObjectEnumerator) {
        [arr removeObject: obj];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", arr);
```

I have read the [Avoiding "NSArray was mutated while being enumerated"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157381/avoiding-nsarray-was-mutated-while-being-enumerated),

> I think deleting from start, affects the enumerator's index of the Objective-C for loop.

and still doubts.

then my question comes .

What Swift did to avoid that Collection was mutated while being enumerated,

And how to analysis that situation under the hood?

Comment: They could just keep the index of objects that return true inside the closure, and then delete them... That's how I'd do it ini Objective-C... I'd use `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` to mimic the "val == num"...

Comment: But you can check https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/11576/commits/ba11a239011b2743e1e52b12e9c9383ef2199f8f the code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating with for .. in on a changing collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67449296/iterating-with-for-in-on-a-changing-collection) - The question is expressed in a slightly different way but is about the same root; the answers provided there should answer your question as well.