# Remove from original array used by for loop Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I notice that when I run this code:

```
var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
for i in letters {
  print(i)
  letters.removeLast()
}
```

it prints:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

and not:

```
a
b
c
```

I'm assuming it's because when I call removeLast() it's removing from a copy of letters and not the original letters array that the for loop is using. How can I remove from the array the for loop is using?

Comment: The for loop **captures** the array, even if you remove items from the original array in the loop the loop runs 6 times.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37997465/1187415

Comment: Oh I see. That makes a lot of sense. Thank you for linking that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already doing that. Or maybe it's not clear to me what you're trying to do.

When you call removeLast() on an array, it removes the last element from the array. In your code, you are calling removeLast() inside of a for loop. This means that, on each iteration of the for loop, the last element of the array is being removed.

However, a for .. in syntax makes a copy of the array. If you want to access the array directly you could use indicies:

```
var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
for (i, letter) in letters.enumerated() {
  if (letters.count <= i) {
      break
  }
  print(letter)
  letters.remove(at: letters.count - 1)
}
```

Comment: All of the elements are still being printed though. If removeLast() did call why would "d", "e", and "f" still be printing?

Comment: @ShayDans have a look at the related link MartinR posted

Comment: Oh okay. I just used letters.indices but I ran into an index out of range error since I is still trying to iterate to 6 I believe. I'm going to try what you have here.

Comment: It worked! I also copied your if check letter count for I and pasted it in the code using the indices method you told me about and that worked as well. Thank you so much I've been on this for hours. I tried upvoting but I don't have enough reputation lol.

Comment: @ShayDans You can still mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

A for loop captures the array being looped over, so even though you are shortening the original array, for is looping over a copy of the original array. This is expected behavior that is explained in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37998032/1630618).

If you really want to do this, then you need to use a while loop:

```
var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
var index = letters.startIndex
while index < letters.endIndex {
    print(letters[index])
    index += 1
    letters.removeLast()
}
```

Comment: Ohh. Thank you so much for specifying that. I see why while loops are preferred over for loops now.