# Is it safe to iterate and remove members from Set data structure?

Tags: swift

I know that, it is not safe to iterate and remove members from `Array` data structure.

```
var datas = ["X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3"]

for (index, data) in datas.enumerated() {
    if data == "Y" || data == "Z" || data == "3" {
        datas.remove(at: index)    // Crash!
    }
}
```

But, how about `Set` data structure? I do not encounter runtime error while running the following code.

```
var datas = Set(["X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3"])

for data in datas {
    if data == "Y" || data == "Z" || data == "3" {
        datas.remove(data)    // No crash.
    }
}
```

But is it safe? What kind of problem can occur if we do so?

Comment: It *is* safe to remove array elements while iterating over its elements, compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/37997465/1187415. What is not safe is to use indices which refer to the original array after that has been mutated.

Comment: O(n) vs O(1) but the array should be reversed

Comment: What you "know" is wrong. It _is_ safe to iterate and remove members from an array. Just enumerate over `datas.enumerated().reversed()` instead of `datas.enumerated()`. Your existing code will then work without crashing. Note too that this has nothing to do with enumeration; it has to do with your use of index numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Iteration over **any sequence** (including array and set) works with a function named `next()`. You can do any manipulation until the `next()` value is available. So **it is OKAY** to remove elements from an array that is being iterated.

The unsafe part is to call index! because removing an item from an array may result in changes in indexes.

Although you can do a safe index-based action with care:

```
var datas = ["X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3"]

for data in datas { //  Not iterating over indices of the array 
    if data == "Y" || data == "Z" || data == "3" {
        guard let index = datas.firstIndex(of: data) else { continue }
        datas.remove(at: index) //  Using the index 
    }
}
```

#### Recap

- ✅ **It is safe** to change the elements of any sequence (including `Array` and `Set`) during iteration.
- ❌ It is **NOT safe** to assume the index and access the sequence directly while changes are happening through the iteration

Comment: Doing `firstIndex` on every loop iteration will cause this to have `O(n^2)` time complexity. And needlessly so, this can be done more simply with `removeAll`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77469652/3141234

Answer (score 1):

This is about data structure.

1. Array structure is a sorted collection, let you access its elements by position (index).
   And accessing at the absent index will cause a fatal error.
2. Set structure is an unsorted collection, which you can access its elements by `key`. It's a hash table behind the scene. That's why all elements should conform to the `Hashable` protocol. When get/delete an element, the Set first looks up from hash table with hash function then returns the value if it exists. There are collusions sometimes, but `remove` function inside Set struct returns an optional value, so it will not crash at all.

Comment: I don't see how that `Set remove()` returning an optional has any relevance to the question.

Comment: I mean it takes an element as an input parameter and returns that element if exists, otherwise Set will do nothing. Sorry for my poor explanation. @HangarRash

Answer (score 1):

The two versions of the code aren't really comparable. You are kind of comparing apples and oranges here.

In the code for arrays, you are removing elements using an index*. The indices of other elements in an array can change when you remove an element, and some indices that used to be valid can become invalid. The loop eventually reaches "3", which had an index of 5 in the original array, but is no longer valid now, since the array only has 4 elements now.

Note that the crash in the array code is not caused by the fact that you are removing elements from the array while iterating over it. The crash is simply because you are using an invalid index. As you will see later, it is completely fine to remove elements from an array while iterating over it, if you don't use an index.

In the code for sets, no indices are involved. You are just using the `Set.remove(_ member: Element)` method. You can never pass an "invalid" element to this method - either the element exists in the set and it will be removed, or the element doesn't exist and nothing happens. So to answer your question: **your code for sets is safe.**

To actually compare the behaviour of arrays and sets, you should use an index to remove an element from the set:

```
var datas = Set(["X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3"])

for index in datas.indices {
    let data = datas[index]
    if data == "Y" || data == "Z" || data == "3" {
        datas.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

Now the code crashes (though I'm not sure if this will *always* happen).

Or, you can also not use an index when removing from the array:

```
var datas = ["X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3"]

for data in datas {
    if data == "Y" || data == "Z" || data == "3" {
        // removeAll { $0 == data } has similar semantics to Set.remove
        datas.removeAll { $0 == data }
    }
}
```

Now this code will not crash.

---

* The first element of the tuple in the sequence returned by `enumerated` isn't actually the index of that element in the collection. It's just a number that goes from 0 to <collection size> - 1. It just so happens that it is the same as the index of each element for an `Array`.

Comment: `remove`ing from a collection will invalidate existing index values you might have. I'm fairly sure that also applies to `data.indices`. Also, if you're going to use `removeAll`, then you don't need the `for` loop. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77469652/3141234

Comment: @Alexander Yes this also applies to `datas.indices`, both when `datas` is an array and when it is a set. That's what I said isn't it? And yes I know I don't need the for loop, but this question isn't asking about how to do things the in the best way possible. It is a question about comparing the behaviours of sets vs arrays. The two code snippets I showed aren't meant to say "this is how you should do it". They are simply another "apple" and another "orange", so that OP can compare two apples together and/or two oranges together.

Comment: ah I just reread it more carefully, I see what you were doing (posing a hypothetical snippet with sets that’s more similar to the array one). I thought it was a suggestion of what to do, instead. Good explanation, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, manually iterating with a `for` loop isn't a good way to do it.

For the Array, you can just use a simple [`removeAll(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/removeall(where:)-5k61r):

```
var data = ["X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3"]
data.removeAll { data == "Y" || data == "Z" || data == "3" }
```

For the Set, you can also use `removeAll`, but set subtraction (e.g. [`subtracting(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/subtracting(_:)-2qge3), or in-place with [`subtract(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/subtract(_:)-7cd3y)) would be more idiomatic:

```swift
var data: Set = ["X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3"]
data.subtract(["Y", "Z", "3"])
```